# Public and Fuel folder in the same subdirectory, but no public/ in the URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, fuelphp, fuelphp-routing

After reading over and over again the [Installation Instructions](http://docs.fuelphp.com/installation/instructions.html#/install_inside_root) for Fuel PHP (which I'm loving), I can't figure out how to make the app work **without the url showing public/**, and without moving the fuel folder from the docroot. (so it's all sefl-contained).

My setup is this:

`/Users/AeroCross/Sites` (this is where MAMP is loading all the files, i.e localhost)
`/Users/AeroCross/Sites/projects/mariocuba` (this is the webroot of the Fuel app)

That contains:

```
    mariocuba/
        .htaccess
        oil
        fuel/
            app/
            core/
            packages/
        public/
            .htaccess
```

The `.htaccess` inside the `mariocuba` folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /public

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The .htaccess inside the `public` folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If I try to load the app (/Users/AeroCross/Sites/projects/mariocuba/), this error appears:

```
Not found.
The requested URL /public/index.php/ was not found on this server.
```

I don't know what to do in here.

I know that's not designed to work that way, and I know that's insecure, but this is for developing and version control purposes. What can I do (with minimal tweaking of the file system) to make this work?

It's worth noting that I have my `config.php` file configured with a `base_url = null` and `index_file = null`.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to access `http://your.domain.com/public/index.php`?

Comment: @JonLin If I do that, I get a Fuel-generated 404 ([like this](http://i.imgur.com/p1ocA.png))

Comment: So where is this `index.php` file supposed to be?

Comment: @JonLin Exactly there. That's the thing: I don't know why I'm getting a 404 since the file is actually there. I'm guessing it's some kind of routing / rewriting failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete your existing .htaccess file from /mariocuba, move the contents of /mariocuba/public (including .htaccess) into /mariocuba and then edit index.php.

Change:

```
/**
 * Path to the application directory.
 */
define('APPPATH', realpath(__DIR__.'/../fuel/app/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

/**
 * Path to the default packages directory.
 */
define('PKGPATH', realpath(__DIR__.'/../fuel/packages/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

/**
 * The path to the framework core.
 */
define('COREPATH', realpath(__DIR__.'/../fuel/core/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

To:

```
/**
 * Path to the application directory.
 */
define('APPPATH', realpath(__DIR__.'/fuel/app/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

/**
 * Path to the default packages directory.
 */
define('PKGPATH', realpath(__DIR__.'/fuel/packages/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

/**
 * The path to the framework core.
 */
define('COREPATH', realpath(__DIR__.'/fuel/core/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

This is detailed in the install instructions here: http://docs.fuelphp.com/installation/instructions.html#/manual

Comment: You are so going to heaven, good sir. I salute you from afar. Worked perfectly!

Comment: This does work, but it's in a level deeper for a reason, it's more secure there. So restricting it in such a way that everything in send to the a level deeper would mimic that and make it less difficult to update the framework when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Add an .htaccess file in your root directory and use the following rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /YOUR_LOCAL_PROJECT_FOLDER/public

    RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index.php/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Note:** You would need to edit the .htaccess once you upload it to the host (since it cannot be dynamically calculated.

Comment: This is working pretty nicely (almost perfectly), but the URL's (by the Assets and Html classes) aren't being generated correctly. They all have `public/` prepended — any thoughts on that?

Comment: Did you set your base_url in the main config?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide everything below the public folder (what I do a lot) use this as the one in the root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

This makes sure all the resources are redirected to public as well. So every thing that's not public is absolutely secure.

Comment: If I add this to my root (`mariocuba/`), going into `localhost/projects/mariocuba` (the root) sends out a 404. `localhost/projects/mariocuba/public` works, tho. It works as you expect, but what I need is that the public folder can be accesses without refering to it in the URL, and having the fuel folder at the same level of the public folder.